# vim: sending tab-completion key against a mapped keystroke

Tags: vim

To switch between buffers without installing any plugins, a good way is to type

```
:b <tab>
```

Which shows all the current buffer names in status bar and you can pick one using cursor keys and enter.

But :b <tab> is 5 keystrokes and I would like to map it to a <leader>.

But setting the following is not working.

```
:nnoremap <Leader>. :b <Tab>
```

It shows ":b ^I" in status bar and doesn't actually open the buffer names on status bar.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: the `buffers` (note the 's') command lists the buffers, while the `buffer` (no 's') command, when it is given an option, will change which buffer is shown in the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `wildcharm` setting. Try this:

```
set wildcharm=<Tab>
nnoremap <leader>. :b <Tab>
```

At least this works here.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I've never heard/read about it.

Comment: YES! That fixed it!!! OSX on MacBook. Thank you:-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it has something to do with `<tab>` not being a real argument for `:b`.

If you drop the tab, as in `nnoremap <leader>. :b<space>` you can hit `<tab>` to get the menu.

You are down to 3 keystrokes to summon the menu but you may still have to hit `<tab>` more times to select the correct buffer and hit `<CR>`. That's a minimum of 4 keystrokes if you want the 1st buffer which is quite nice but what if you want the 7th or 12th buffer?

May I suggest another way?

```
nnoremap <leader>. :ls<CR>:b<Space>
```

With this mapping, a list of buffers (`:ls`) is displayed and the `:b` command is initiated, waiting for a buffer number as argument. That's 4 keystrokes (`,.5<CR>`), whatever buffer you want to jump to (well, if you have 10 or more buffers that would be 5 keystrokes but you get the point).

I don't know how you could make it shorter beside mapping a single key (like `<F11>` or whatever).